# How to open connection to MySQL DataBase on another PC?

Tags: mysql, database, unity-game-engine

At the moment I'm working on a small programm in Unity, which reads and displays data from my MySQL database. I just started programming, so the project may seem very easy for many of you, but I'm having a huge problem. 
My DB-connection works fine in the Unity Editor, but only on the computer on which my database is located. That is kinda logical, because my code connects to the database through localhost, but what settings do I need to change in MySQL to make my database available from another computer? I guess, I'll probably have to connect to some kind of external server (like an intermediary), but still...  maybe there is some other way to make my connection work? Thank you in advance for kind help!

Comment: You don't connect to database directly. You connect to a server which communicates with the database through any web languages like php .

Answer (score 0):

> but what settings do I need to change in MySQL to make my database available from another computer

If you want to connect from another computer to your local DB, you need to know the IP of the computer where your DB is running and connect to it.

Make sure your network settings (port) do allow it and check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql).

Quote:

> What is disabled by default is remote root access.